# Dual instances of Service, Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, groovy

SOLVED - Turns out if both the base class (ActivityRuleServiceImpl) and the derived class (MyCompanyActivityRuleServiceImpl) have the @Service  annotation then they are two different service instances.  When I removed the @Service from the base class I now only get one instance.

---

I have a spring-boot application. there is a core library that compiles to a jar, and an application that sits on top of that.
The core has a Service called ActivityRuleService (And ...Impl) defined like this

```
interface ActivityRuleService { ...
```

and the impl

```
@Slf4j
@CompileStatic
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Service
class ActivityRuleServiceImpl implements ActivityRuleService {...
```

Then in the app that uses the core library I have

```
interface MyCompanyActivityRuleService extends ActivityRuleService {
```

and

```
@Slf4j
@CompileStatic
@Primary
@Service
class MyCompanyActivityRuleServiceImpl extends ActivityRuleServiceImpl implements 
MyCompanyActivityRuleService { ...
```

In the core code I use code like

```
@Autowire
ActivityRuleService activityRuleService
```

and in the app code it is like

```
@Autowire
MyCompanyActivityRuleService activityRuleService
```

The problem is I get **two instances** of ActivityRuleService. The base class ActitityRuleServiceImpl has a @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000L) task in it and it gets hit twice instead of the expected once per minute, and the hits are 1 ms. apart.

What I need is that the override class MyCompanyActivityRuleServiceImpl should be the one and only injected instance. Even if a class in the core has an @Autowired to ActivityRuleService it should get the one from the application level MyCompany...

Any ideas?

Comment: One way would be to make `ActivityRuleServiceImpl` abstract.

Comment: Or use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: You can also use named qualifiers. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation